# Can't get the values from the created plist file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

I'm the new one in ios development and I can't read the values from the plist I've created with using previous method. The read method returns (null) (null). Who can help me?

Here I create a plist:

```
- (void)createAppPlist {

    plistPath = [self getDataFileDir];
    // Create the data structure

    rootElement = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
    NSError *err;
    name = @"North America";
    country = @"United States";

    continentElement = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:name, country, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name", @"Country", nil]];

    [rootElement setObject:continentElement forKey:@"Continent"];

    //Create plist file and serialize XML

    data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:rootElement format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:&err];
    if(data)
    {
        [data writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error has occures %@", err);
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", rootElement);
    NSLog(@"%@", data);

}
```

And here I'm trying to get the values..

```
-(void)readAppPlist
{
    plistPath = [self getDataFileDir];
    NSMutableDictionary *propertyDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    name = [propertyDict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    country = [propertyDict objectForKey:@"Country"];

    NSLog(@"%@     %@", name, country);
}
```

Comment: do you want to store xml or plist?

Comment: @ShurupuS Can you show your getDataFileDir as well? If the directoryPath is pointing to bundle, you cannot write the plist to it.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara I would like to use plist

Comment: @Anupdas - (NSString *)getDataFileDir
{
    // Get path of data.plist file to be created
    
    NSArray *dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath =[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
    plistPath = [[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName] stringByAppendingPathExtension:dataFileExtension];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", plistPath);
    return plistPath;
}

Comment: @ShurupuS , i have posted code for it. use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following code to create and read Plist in document directory, you can change storing path according to your requirement

```
- (void)createAppPlist {

//    plistPath = [self getDataFileDir];
    // Create the data structure

    NSMutableDictionary *rootElement = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];

    NSString *name = @"North America";
    NSString *country = @"United States";


    NSMutableDictionary *continentElement = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:name, country, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name", @"Country", nil]];

    [rootElement setObject:continentElement forKey:@"Continent"];

    //Create plist file
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPlist.plist"];
    [rootElement writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"%@", rootElement);
}

-(void)readAppPlist
{
    // Get pList file path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPlist.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *propertyDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSDictionary *rootDict = [propertyDict valueForKey:@"Continent"];

    // now read all elements inside, it will print key an value
    [rootDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
        NSLog(@"[%@]->[%@]",key,obj);
    }];
}
```

Comment: why do you declare the variables inside the method. What is the idea? Because in my example I don't do that.

Comment: its just a sample, you can declare them at class level, make respective changes accordingly.

Comment: Because in my example I don't do that. And I don't  use ARC - to clean the memory I need to write a deaalock method or release the variables inside it in the end?

Comment: you can make NON ARC by adding autorelease and dealloc to respective objects.